# python to search separated words

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract separated multi words from a python list with two different list as a query string. My sentences list is

```
lst = ['we have the terrible HIV epidemic that takes down the life expectancy of the African ','and I take the regions down here','The poorest are down']
lst_verb = ['take','go','wake']
lst_prep = ['down','up','in']
import re
output=[]
item = 'down'
p = re.compile(r'(?:\w+\s+){1,20}'+item)
for i in lst:
    output.append(p.findall(i))

for item in output:
    print(item)
```

with this i am able to extract word from the list, However I am only want to extract separated multiwords, i.e it should extract the word from the list "and I take the regions down here".
furthermore, I want to use the word from lst_verb and lst_prep as query string.
for example

```
re.findall(r \lst_verb+'*.\b'+ \lst_prep)
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: what you are saying is that you don't understand what your script does. take some time to understand how it is working and you'll see it is very simple to achieve what you want

Comment: Yes, I would like to use those 2 lst_verb and lst_prep as query string in regex, but I dont know to implement it in the regex. my python skill is very low. Thank you in advance for your help..

Comment: yes regular expressions are indeed something difficult to understand, even for seasoned programmers. i think that you can do what you want with simple string functions

Comment: Could you please give an example for my case. Thanks

Comment: p=re.compile(r'(?s)(\btake|go|wake|\b.*?\bdown|up|in|\b){1,20}')
I tried this regex, however i think is not very scalable solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like

`(?is)^(?=.*\b(take)\b)(?=.*?\b(go)\b)(?=.*\b(where)\b)(?=.*\b(wake)\b).*`

To match Multiple words 
like this  [your example](https://regex101.com/r/VOHEJK/2)

use functions to create regex string from the verbs and prep.
hope this helps